# In-App-Purchase sandbox testing error

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am getting the below error for sandbox testing while test in app purchase

> you are not authorized to make purchases of this in app in sandbox at
>   this time

How to avoid this error

Comment: have u created test account for testing in sandbox?

Answer (score 26):

Make sure of the following:
1. The test account created is from the same developer portal from which you generated your provisioning profile.
2. The test account still exists and was not deleted from there.
3. Use the same identifier for which you created the in-app purchase for your app in iTunesConnect.

Comment: What do you mean by "Test account created is from the same developer portal"??

Comment: This means, you must have registered your in-app identifiers to some iTunesConnect portal. Test accounts for testing in-app must be registered on iTunesConnect account where your identifier is listed.

Comment: Mine is because I deleted this test account in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 8):

I found that I got this error when trying to log in with the wrong test account. One not connected to my iTunes connect account.

Log into iTunes Connect and double check you are using the correct email address as in the test account.

Otherwise here is a pretty good post about all the checks you need to go through to get the in app purchases working in sandbox mode, each has a short blurb on completing each one: http://ireviewappsblog.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/adding-in-app-purchases-in-sand-box-mode/

It covers adding the app to iTunes connecting, setting up the developer account and then also adding the code in xCode to get it working.

Answer (score 5):

1.Check in-app product identifier on itunesconnect is same as you are using in your application

2.Check the bundle identifier for your app are same in the development profile & & itunes connect

3.The status of in app purchase for which you are testing on iTunes connect should be "Ready to submit"

4.Delete the app from your device clean its build from xcode if you have changed bundle identifier or provisioning profile

5.No documents agreement should be pending on iTunes connect or developer.

Comment: Is it OK if the IAP that I'm testing is NOT "Ready to Submit" but is "Approved"?

Comment: I satisfied all #1-#5 but still have this error. This happened to me recently. It has been working until this week. Very weird.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that your test account does not exist any longer. I found that you are still able to log in with a deleted test account but you are not allowed to make purchases and you will see the same message as you described.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are you are using provisioning profile from different developer account. check it once again.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** Go to settings.

**Step 2 :** Select iTunes & Settings

**Step 3 :** Scroll to the bottom. There is a section for **SANDBOX ACCOUNT**

**Step 4 :** Sign in there using your Sandbox account

Now test your app & it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. For sandbox, only sandbox testers can make purchases.
2. Make sure testers NEVER use the sandbox accounts to make actual purchases; this will convert the sandbox account to a live account.
3. Only Sandbox Testers can make test purchases. It's NOT the users who are listed in Internal and External testers lists. Check `iTunes Connect => Users and Roles => Sandbox Testers`.